# Do memory addresses contain implicit hex digits?

Tags: gdb, memory-address

What is the value of a memory address that is less than 12 hex digits on a 64-bit computer?

For instance, when I run gdb on a simple assembly program and run `(gdb) info frame` I get:

```
Stack level 0, frame at 0x7fffffffd970:
 rip = 0x40052f in main (file.s:11); saved rip = 0x7ffff7a2d830
 source language asm.
 Arglist at 0x7fffffffd960, args: 
 Locals at 0x7fffffffd960, Previous frame's sp is 0x7fffffffd970
 Saved registers:
  rbp at 0x7fffffffd960, rip at 0x7fffffffd968
```

The first part of the second line `rip = 0x40052f in main (file.s:11)` I believe states the value of the instruction pointer when I called `info frame`. But why is the memory address it holds not 12 hex digits?

Also, if I type `(gdb) x 0x7fffffffd968` (which I expect to be `0x7ffff7a2d830`) I get:

```
0x7fffffffd968: 0xf7a2d830
```

Does this mean that any memory address with less than 12 hex digits contains an implicit `7ff...`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.  On x86 or x86_64, a memory address is simply a number, but is commonly displayed using hexadecimal.  And like most number notation systems, a shorter number just means a much smaller value, or if you like, there are implicit zeros before it.

So just like the decimal string "12" is much smaller than "12654321", the address `0x40052f` is much smaller than the address `0x7ffff7a2d830`.  The two addresses are almost certainly in different virtual memory maps.  (On Linux, you can view virtual memory maps by `cat /proc/{pid}/maps`.)

When you used the gdb `x` command, you didn't see the value you expected because gdb took a guess at what kind of data your address points at.  The first time you use `x` in a gdb session, it defaults to showing 4 bytes (32 bits) per element, as though the address points at an array of `uint32_t`.  Since addresses on x86_64 are 8 bytes (64 bits), you need `x/g` to tell gdb the element size is 8 bytes.